# How to display how long it has been since the latest date/time in a column

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a column with a list of dates and times (H4:H) and I have a cell (H2) where I want to show how long it has been since the most recent date from the column below (H4:H). I would like it to display time if it is less than a day, days if it is less than a month, months if it is less than a year, etc. I know I first need to get the most recent date, and then I need to see how long it has been since that date, in the manner I described previously. That will be what is displayed. Please let me know if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help:

```
= IF(INT(NOW() - MAX(H4:H)) > 365, CONCATENATE(INT(NOW() - MAX(H4:H) / 365), " year(s)"), IF(INT(NOW() - MAX(H4:H)) > 30, CONCATENATE(INT(NOW() - MAX(H4:H) / 30), " month(s)"), IF (INT(NOW() - MAX(H4:H)) > 1, CONCATENATE(INT(NOW() - MAX(H4:H)), " day(s)"), MAX(H4:H))))
```

Basically I calculated the the time difference in the form of days using:

```
= NOW() - MAX(H4:H)
```

Then I checked if that value is greater 365, if yes, display the number of years, otherwise, check if the value is greater than 30, if yes, display the number of months, otherwise, check if the value is greater than 1, if yes, display the number of days, otherwise just display the time.

---

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF(DAYS(MAX(H4:H), H2)=0, TEXT(MAX(H4:H)-H2, "[hh]:mm:ss"), 
 IF(DAYS(MAX(H4:H), H2)=1, "1 day",
 IF(DAYS(MAX(H4:H), H2)<30, DAYS(MAX(H4:H), H2)&" days", 
 IF(DAYS(MAX(H4:H), H2)=30, "1 month", 
 IF(DAYS(MAX(H4:H), H2)<365, INT(DAYS(MAX(H4:H), H2)/30)&" months", 
 IF(DAYS(MAX(H4:H), H2)=365, "1 year", 
 IF(DAYS(MAX(H4:H), H2)>365, ROUND(DAYS(MAX(H4:H), H2)/365, 2)&" years")))))))
```

[image]